# Output partial request Powershell with webrequest

Tags: powershell

On some server i've got a ASP.NET handler that runs a job. This job can run easily for 10 minutes. I'm calling this handler on my build server using Powershell with this script:

```
$url = 'http://<joburl>'

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ($url) -method GET
Write-Output -InputObject $response
```

This is working fine to just call the URL and let this job execute. But my job is showing status messages. It flushes it's output buffer constantly to show this message during the request. So in the browser it's showing these messages when it's still waiting on the job to be finished. My Powershell script is showing these messages after the request has been finished. Is there any way I can show these status messages when the request is still loading?

Comment: Instead of storing the return values in a var and then outputting them, try  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ('http://<joburl>') -method GET

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately that didn't seem to help. I still don't get my output directly printed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not storing your result to a variable if you want to see it in real time. Here is a good intro to invoke-webrequest. And here is a sample.

This will output the data directly to the console as it comes in and is parsed.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=Powershell" -Method GET
```

This will store all data in a variable, wait for all data to be received and then output the data to the console.

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&q=Powershell" -Method GET
$result
```

Try these samples to see if this is the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Invoke-WebRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx). With that you get an object as a response with a property named Content so you can do:

```
$(Invoke-WebRequest <uri>).Content
```

To get the result from your page.

Hope that helps!